# Pytorch - Loss is decreasing but Accuracy not improving

Tags: python, image-classification, pytorch

It seems loss is decreasing and the algorithm works fine. But accuracy doesn't improve and stuck.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.utils.data

file_path_0 = [f for f in listdir("data/0") if isfile(join("data/0", f))]
file_path_1 = [f for f in listdir("data/1") if isfile(join("data/1", f))]

data_x = []
data_y = []

for i in range(len(file_path_0)):
    image = cv2.imread("data/0/" + file_path_0[i])
    # image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    data_x.append(image)
    data_y.append(0)

for i in range(len(file_path_1)):
    image = cv2.imread("data/1/" + file_path_1[i])
    # image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    data_x.append(image)
    data_y.append(1)

data_x = np.array(data_x).astype(np.double) / 255
data_y = np.array(data_y).astype(np.double).reshape(-1, 1)

data_x, data_y = shuffle(data_x, data_y)

t_data_x = torch.stack([torch.Tensor(i) for i in data_x])  # transform to torch tensors
t_data_y = torch.stack([torch.tensor(i, dtype=torch.float) for i in data_y])

##############################

batch_size = 10

t_dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(t_data_x, t_data_y)  # create your dataset

train_size = int(0.8 * len(t_dataset))
test_size = len(t_dataset) - train_size
train_dataset, test_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(t_dataset, [train_size, test_size])

train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)  # create your dataloader
test_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)  # create your dataloader


class Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(720, 10, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 5, kernel_size=3)

        self.mp1 = nn.MaxPool2d(5)

        self.fc = nn.Linear(2550, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        in_size = x.size(0)
        x = F.relu(self.mp1(self.conv1(x)))
        x = x.view(in_size, -1)  # Dense
        x = self.fc(x)
        x = F.sigmoid(x)

        return x


model = Net()

optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)


def train(epoch):
    model.train()
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        data, target = Variable(data), Variable(target)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = F.binary_cross_entropy(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        if batch_idx % 10 == 0:
            print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                epoch, batch_idx * len(data), len(train_dataloader.dataset),
                       100. * batch_idx / len(train_dataloader),
                loss.data.item()))


def test():
    model.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    for data, target in test_dataloader:
        data, target = Variable(data, requires_grad=True), Variable(target)
        output = model(data)
        # sum up batch loss
        test_loss += F.binary_cross_entropy(output, target, size_average=False).data.item()
        # get the index of the max log-probability
        pred = output.data.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]
        correct += pred \
            .eq(target
                .data
                .view_as(pred).long()) \
            .cpu() \
            .sum()

    test_loss /= len(test_dataloader.dataset)
    print('\nTest set: Average loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {}/{} ({:.0f}%)\n'.format(
        test_loss, correct, len(test_dataloader.dataset),
        100. * correct / len(test_dataloader.dataset)))


for epoch in range(1, 10):
    train(epoch)
    test()
```

> Train Epoch: 7 [0/249 (0%)]   Loss: 0.537067 Train Epoch: 7 [100/249
>   (40%)]    Loss: 0.597774 Train Epoch: 7 [200/249 (80%)]   Loss: 0.554897
>   Test set: Average loss: 0.5094, Accuracy: 37/63 (58%) Train Epoch: 8
>   [0/249 (0%)]  Loss: 0.481739 Train Epoch: 8 [100/249 (40%)]   Loss:
>   0.564388 Train Epoch: 8 [200/249 (80%)]   Loss: 0.517878 Test set: Average loss: 0.4522, Accuracy: 37/63 (58%) Train Epoch: 9 [0/249
>   (0%)] Loss: 0.420650 Train Epoch: 9 [100/249 (40%)]   Loss: 0.521278
>   Train Epoch: 9 [200/249 (80%)]    Loss: 0.480884 Test set: Average loss:
>   0.3944, Accuracy: 37/63 (58%)

Answer (score 1):

Such a difference in Loss and Accuracy happens. It's pretty normal. The accuracy just shows how much you got right out of your samples. So in your case, your accuracy was 37/63 in 9th epoch.

When calculating loss, however, you also take into account how well your model is predicting the correctly predicted images. When the loss decreases but accuracy stays the same, you probably better predict the images you already predicted. Maybe your model was 80% sure that it got the right class at some inputs, now it gets it with 90%. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your training and testing data should be different, for the reason that it is easy to overfit the training data, but the true goal is for the algorithm to perform on data it has not seen before. Its normal to see your training performance continue to improve even though your test data performance has converged.